# Upgraded to iOS 7 beta / Xcode 5 beta and receiving warning "CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS specified without a valid Developer Signing Identity for iOS"

Tags: xcode, ios7, xcode5

Just upgraded to iOS 7 beta (and Xcode 5 beta) and am receiving the following warning when I build a preexisting app that I'm moving to iOS 7

`Check dependencies: warning: CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS specified without a valid Developer Signing Identity for iOS.`

However, when I check the `Code Signing Entitlements` flag in my Build Settings, I actually don't have a Code Signing Entitlement defined:

[image]

Any ideas? Is this now required in iOS 7?  If so, how would I define a Code Signing Entitlement?

Comment: How is this off topic? It's about a build system called Xcode that hundreds of thousands of people use. It's the top result on Google for multiple issues.

Comment: It's off-topic because it deals with two pieces of software, iOS 7 and Xcode 5, that are in beta and covered by an NDA.

Comment: @AlexsanderAkers, I'm no lawyer, but in section 10.1 of the `iOS Program Standard Agreement` it specifically refers to non-public features.  This questions deals with a feature that was included in Xcode 4 (public domain), but is throwing a warning in Xcode 5.  To avoid breaching, the answerer to this question should avoid saying if it's required in iOS 7, but (again IMHO), if he/she says what steps were taken to remove this warning with existing Xcode 4.x procedures, I think it's still very much in the realm of not violating the NDA.  I'm going to flag this question to get further clarity.

Comment: You will find answers to that question on apple's developer forums (provided you have a developer account), just search "CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS" over there.

Comment: @AlexsanderAkers - Whether something is on topic and whether it is covered by NDA are orthogonal concepts. This covers developer tools, so it is on topic.

Comment: The SDK and the version of Xcode are non public. Only available to those with paid developer accounts who've agreed to the NDA. Use the developer forums. Otherwise you may see stricter betas in the future. How hard is that to comply with?

Comment: Xcode 5 is a preview developer release and not meant to sign anything. So don't worry about this error till Xcode 5 final comes out.. you can still test your app in iOS 7 Beta. All of the contents are under NDA and should only be discussed in the closed apple developer forums

Comment: We just upgraded to Xcode 5 final release, still got this problem while building by commmand line

Answer (score 18):

The problem is not with the `Code Signing Entitlements`. The problem is most probably with the `Code Signing Identity`.

In Xcode 4 the automatic profile selector was looking for a profile named: **iPhone Developer**. However, it seems in Xcode 5 the automatic profile selector is looking for a profile named: **iOS Developer** (as it can be seen in your screenshot) which most probably doesn't exist.

In order to fix this problem try manually selecting an existing profile from the `Code Signing Identity` drop-down list.

Comment: Automatic selection seems to work for new Xcode 5 projects without any issues, but it fails to work with existing Xcode 4.x projects. I have to select the exact name of the profile.

Answer (score 9):

Keep automatic identity setting, but select a profile under "Provisioning Profile" setting and Xcode will pick up correct identities.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having this problem because you are using Jenkins and it can't find the right code signing identity, you can fix it by setting it manually [image: Jenkins manual Code Signing Identity]

It will automatically choose the right provisioning profile if it's present in the Jenkins node.