# Xcode 5 command line Code Sign error

Tags: ios7, xcode5

Has anyone experienced the case where Xcode 5  (Build version 5A11344j)  command line tool failed to build a previously-successfully-built Project in  Xcode 4.6.3 (Build version 4H1503).

The error message is like:

"
Check dependencies

Code Sign error: No codesigning identities found: No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“”) were found.

CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.0'
"

Any insight is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Looks kind of related (also note comments about NDA): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035440/upgraded-to-ios-7-beta-xcode-5-beta-and-receiving-warning-code-sign-entitleme?rq=1

Comment: @user2615915 did any of the answers help? If so please accept an answer or offer a comment about the ongoing issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks all for your comment. It turned out that a later version of Xcode (Build version 5A1413) fixed it. Hope this is helpful to other folks as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have a relevant provisional profile. The thing I always do that solve this kind of issue is clean it all.

Yep, A simple cleaning and then build can solve that. If Xcode crash after the build just rerun and clean again and then that suppose to work.

I know this answer has no logic but that works for me dozen of times maybe that would help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Set the code signing identities and provisioning profile. Don't forget to check the bundle identifier.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible causes to this issue. It sounds like you may not have setup an identity certificate or that certificate is out of date (open keychain application on Mac or check the references I've added). The primary things one should check are that the Accounts Section in Xcode Preferences is configured correctly, the developer portal certificates and profiles (especially certificate expiration dates), and the local keychain application on your Mac (you may have expired certificates being used). Apple has a technical note that lists further possibilities ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2318/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013777)).